# Expressjs ejs fn.apply error 'View is not a constructor'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, apply, ejs

I'm trying to have some stuff done before the original app.get is called.

I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_in_monkey-patching) page, I tried what they did and it mostly worked, expect for when I try to use a rendering engine with it.

The code I'm using (`app` is the result of `express()`):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ejs = require('ejs');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var originalfoo = app.get;
app.get = function() {
    // Do stuff before calling function
    console.log(arguments);
    // Call the function as it would have been called normally:
    originalfoo.apply(this, arguments);
    // Run stuff after, here.
};

app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
    //res.send('hello world') // This works
    res.render('index'); // This crashes
});
```

res.render gives me this error: `TypeError: View is not a constructor`

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

PS: `/views/index.ejs` does exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to return original function invocation, otherwise the decorated `app.get` method is no longer returning anything unlike the original:

```
app.get = function() {
    // Call the function as it would have been called normally:
    return originalfoo.apply(this, arguments);
};
```